# Loading external SWF file issue

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I am building a SWF player which loads external SWF's.

Rite Now.
I could call the external SWF using URLRequest.

but I am getting 2 problems

1. How to run the SWF with the frame rate of the actual SWF movie. How can I know the frameRate of external SWF dynamically from within AS3.
2. I have set a layer of 450px by 350px. How do I scale the external SWF with showall property to fit in the layer.

Answer (score 1):

see this url for the framerate :  http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=112

try to use the `loaderInfo` property of the loader object to resize your swf,

ex :

```
var l:Loader = new Loader();

l.load(new URLRequest("urlToYourSwf"));
l.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeFunction);

// completeFunction 

l.loaderInfo.width = xxx;
l.loaderInfo.height = xxx;
addChild(l);
```